# probability that there is an edge with m vertices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

> What is the probability that there is an edge in an undirected random graph having m vertices?[assume prob of edge between 2 vertices - 1/2]

how to think in this type of problem.

probability that an edge exists between 2 vertices = 1/2

$(1/2)^{m-1}$ is probability of m length path.

[image]

Comment: who told you it's $1/2$ ?

Comment: sir i am assuming a fair case(2 possibilities - edge present or not present).

Comment: Are you interested in the probability of an edge or of a path length $m$?

Comment: probability that an edge contains m vertices

Comment: So you have $a_1-a_2\dots-a_m$ with vertices $a_i$ and an edge between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ for each $i$. The term for that is "path", not "edge".

Comment: sir Qn says if there is an edge what is probability that it contains m vertices(path containing m vertices is different from edge through m vertices)

Comment: I am not understanding the question.  An edge only ever has two vertices, its two end-points.  The *graph* can have $m$ vertices, sure.  Are you asking what the probability is that a random graph with $m$ vertices has at least one edge where each edge independently is included with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$?  What is difficult about that problem?  Could you answer the related question, "what is the probability that when flipping $\binom{m}{2}$ fair coins in a row that they all turn out to be tails?"

Comment: If you are asking what the probability is that a random graph contains a **path** of length $m$, then we've lost a variable here somewhere... how many vertices are in the graph?  Also $m$?  So you are asking what the probability is that there is a hamiltonian cycle?  Or are there $n$ vertices instead which hasn't been mentioned yet until now?  Why would you expect this to be easily calculable?

Comment: @JMoravitz sir this is a question in competetive exam - exact question "What is the probability that there is an edge in an undirected random graph having "8" vertices?[assume prob of edge between 2 vertices - 1/2]". I am a beginner.

Comment: @JMoravitz Regarding - "what is the probability that when flipping (mC2) fair coins in a row that they all turn out to be tails?"  --> My attempt: (1/2)^(mC2)

Comment: I understood what u r refering to - an edge has exactly 2 end vertices. If an edge has some 6 vertices in between with 2 end vertices, such edge possible right?

Comment: @JMoravitz sir pls see above pic. Please feel free to correct if i am wrong

Comment: There must be some sort of language barrier here or translation error.  An edge has two vertices.  Period.  Never any more, never any less  (*unless you are talking about hypergraphs or loops*).  If you have "two end vertices" and "six vertices inbetween them" what you are more probably describing is a **path**, not an edge.  A path is made up of *many edges*.

Comment: In that case of path thru 8 vertices, probability = $(1/2)^7$. Please correct me if wrong

Comment: That would be the probability that very specifically those seven edges exist in your graph, and the probability that a very specific length-7 path exists.  That is very different than asking what the probability is that at least one length-7 path exists in your graph.  It could be the case that the path $A,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_6,B$ doesn't exist because it is missing an edge but the path $x_1,x_3,x_5,x_2,x_4,x_6,A,B$ does exist or some other arrangement or collection of vertices.

Comment: oh yes, (1/2)^7 indicates any path among A, B and all $x_i$ 's . But then what is probability of path A, x1, x2, x3.. x6, B, then again divide (1/2)^7 by 8! ?

Comment: Certainly not.  It is in fact a very difficult question which I only see a solution that involves heavily tedious casework.  See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642309/probability-of-having-a-path-of-a-given-length-in-a-random-graph?rq=1) for another discussion on the problem for a partial but still incomplete solution to get an idea on the bounds.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you sir, i will go thru it ..

Comment: You mention that "this is a question in competitive exam", could you share a link to the original source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I misreading this? By definition every edge exists between precisely two vertices, except for loops which exist on one.  Between fewer than 1 vertices you havent got an edge at all.  The point is, every edge has two endpoints. A single edge cannot connect more than two vertices. Thus $m$ can only be 1 or 2. For all other values of $m$ the probability must necessarily be 0 because the scenario is impossible.

---

Since every complete graph has $\binom{m}{2}$ two-vertex edges, and potentially $m$ one-vertex edges (loops), then in a completely random graph there are $\binom{m}{2} + m $ total edges. These are the only possible undirected edges in a simple graph. If you want generalize then there is an infinitude of possible edges between any two vertices.

So $\binom{m}{2} + m $ is the possible number of edges.  Or simply $\binom{m}{2}$, if there are no loops. This is the denominator of any probability fraction you come up with.

Comment: sir pls see my above comment and pic in edited part. Pls correct if i am wrong.

Comment: The bottom two graphs you ask are different are in fact the same graph.

Comment: What you are asking is not graph theory at all, but Euclidean geometry.  You want to know the probability that $m-2$ points are colinear with some other two points.  I assure you such a geometrical figure would be nearly impossible if chosen randomly.

Comment: exactly. Why it is not possible? can u please elaborate (atlease some hints)

Comment: In case of path with 8 vertices, probability of such path existence = $(1/2)^7$. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Because its impossible to randomly choose just 3 points that do this, much less $m$.  Two points - your endpoints - make a line. It doesnt matter where in space you choose them, they will always make a line.  Now randomly choose a third point anywhere in space. Do you think its more or less likely it will be on the line?

Comment: agreed..........

Comment: This seems a very incorrect interpretation of the problem.  If the problem really were about geometry and asking if some collection of points were colinear, then the entire premise about edges appearing or not appearing between vertices wouldn't have been relevant.  In my interpretation, this question is about random graphs from graph theory and probability and asking about existence of paths.

Comment: Your interpretation is no more relevant than mine is. In fact its less so.  If you know better then feel free to provide an answer.  I gave a valid answer and correctly interpreted the problem - did you read the body of my answer or are you basing your criticism (and your down vote) on the commentary beneath it? Are you also ignoring the fact that the OP questioner verified the geometric interpretation, and all of the other points he discusses? Or you going to insist that you know the interpretation better than either the OP or myself?